# Angular 2 cli ng new * is missing a bunch of folders

Tags: angular, public, directory-structure

Not sure how to ask this properly so please bear with me as I slog my way through this query ::

I'm learning Angular 2 and there's a step in the tutorial when a new file is being created and placed in the 'public' folder. However, there isn't a public folder in my directory.

I've recreated a new directory several times [ng new project-name] but it keeps creating the same directory structure, sans a bunch of folders that are evident in the tutorial. The only folders created are 'e2e', 'node_modules', & 'src' ... then there's a bunch of json, js, etc., files in the root with those 3 folders.

I'm missing 'config', 'dist', 'public', 'tmp' & 'typings'. At least that's what I see in the tutorial.

Question #1 is a bit broad since I don't know what to expect (other than what I see in the tutorial) but is this to be expected due to Node or NPM versions?

Question #2; If I manually create these folders in the editor, will that work properly? I'm not sure if there are any dependencies that need to be set up via the angular cli. Which leads me to my last question ...

Question #3; how do I manually create new folders in a directory that work properly? The tutorial says this would never be necessary which is why I'm curious about how to get around issues like this.

Thanks much.

Windows 10

Node v6.9.4

NPM v3.10.10

Comment: which tutorial are you following?  The [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) uses the [quickstart-seed](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) which doesn't have that kind of directory structure....

Comment: It's on YouTube by The Net Ninja.Thanks for the official lesson link. I'll definitely check it out. 

What I'm seeing is everyone teaching about the functionality of Angular 2 but everyone I've found seems to skate over how to customize the directory itself. It might be because it's assumed knowledge, but given that I don't know what I don't know ... heh, you know what I mean :)

Comment: just looking at the youtube videos, it seems that the video was recorded using a previous version of angular-cli that used SystemJS, while the current releases 1.0.0-beta.11 and later use Webpack.  From the perspective of learning angular, the change shouldn't change much, because the code you are actually writing will be in the src directory exclusively.  There may be *minor* changes in the way the build and serve scripts, but unless you are planning to change the build process itself, the change in folder structure isn't a factor.

Comment: I suppose if you *really* wanted to have the exact directory structure used in that tutorial series, you could force install the version of Angular-CLI that is in use in the videos, but I really wouldn't recommend it;  Webpack is  definitely the future of Angular-CLI https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-14

Comment: Some more poking around the internet led me —finally— to notice a styles.css file residing in the src folder, so you're most likely correct that it's due to a version issue. Opening it exposes a placeholder stating that using it will affect the project globally. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed is outdate. In the newer versions the folders structure is different but you can find what you need:

There have been some special config files merely for the use of SystemJS. Since the CLI now uses Webpack, those were gone, and so went the config folder. The few remaining configuration files live in the root (angular-cli.json, karma.conf.js, protractor.conf.js).

The **public** folder is now an assets property in angular-cli.json. It's an array of strings. Each string can match files that will copied to the output folder (dist by default) as-is (for example *.config files get copied to dist/{filename}.config). If the string matches a folder name (assets for example), the folder itself will be copied with the same name (for example to dist/assets).

The **typings** folder was for a tool that has the same name that loads TypeScript definition files for JavaScript libraries (the files that provide autocomplete for non-TypeScript libraries). Now in TypeScript 2, there's a new way to load those definitions, which is loading them as NPM packages under the name @types (similar to how Angular 2 packages are under @angular), which TypeScript understands and loads by itself without other tools.